# from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyModbusTCP'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pymodbustcp

I am trying to get the values from the registers using pymodbus but i am facing issues with import pymodule .Please help me on this?

I tried pip install pymodbus and pip install but still getting the error.
I tried this too from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.